# basic4android call additional library's method

Tags: basic4android

I added java library to my project. now I want to use Reflector lib to call an static method of the added java library.

The way this method is called in java lib was:

```
Adad.setTestMode(true);
```

Now I am wondering how I could call this method in B4A.
As Much as I know I should write something like this:

```
Dim r As Reflector
r.RunStaticMethod("ir.adad.Adad" , "setTesMode" , ??? , Null)
```

But I don't know what to put instead of `???` in the above statement.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately as B4A forum guys only respond to paid members questions, I had to figure out the solution myself:

```
Dim args1(1) As Object
args1(0) = True 
Dim types(1) As String
types(0) = "java.lang.boolean"

Dim r As Reflector  
r.RunStaticMethod("ir.adad.Adad" , "setTestMode" , args1 ,  types)
```